# How to apply CSS3 animations to table-cells

Tags: jquery, css, slide, css-animations

I have 2 `table-cells` below. One is hidden, the other is not:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <td class="mobile-caller-pos" style="width:100%; height:50px; background:blue;">Content 1</td>
    <td class="mobile-caller-pos-dark" style="width:100%; height:50px; background: red; diplay:none">Content 2</td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I have simple jquery, so that when `mobile-caller-pos-dark` is clicked, it hides and reveals `mobile-caller-pos-dark`:

```
$(document).on('click', '.mobile-caller-pos', function(t) {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.hide();
  $this.siblings('.mobile-caller-pos-dark').show();
});
```

How can I use a CSS3 (or jQyery) transition so that rather than an instant reveal, `mobile-caller-pos-dark` appears to slide in from the right, over the top of `mobile-caller-pos`?

Answer (score 0):

`.show()` and `.hide()` affect the `display` property in CSS and are not animatable

With that being said, there are several ways to do this. The first is to remove the width/padding/margins from the first element:

```
$(document).on('click', '.mobile-caller-pos', function (t) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.empty().css({"width":"0","margin":"0", "padding":"0"});
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/raX4Q/)

The second is to slide the second element in from the left using `position:absolute`

```
$(document).on('click', '.mobile-caller-pos', function (t) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.siblings('.mobile-caller-pos-dark').css({"display":"block"});
    setTimeout(function() { $this.siblings('.mobile-caller-pos-dark').css({"left":"0"}); },0);
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/raX4Q/1/)

You could also animate the width of the red from 0 to 100% with `right:0`, slide the blue to the left using `position:absolute; left:-100%` and many other options. You might [**check here**](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions/) for more explanation